# How can I change the entry point of a Flutter app running in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have a Flutter app that I usually run in VSCode using the Flutter run command.  The app has 3 different flavors and a different entry point for each flavor.  Here is how I run the app on VSCode:

```
flutter run --target lib/main_production.dart --flavor production
```

I would like to know how to run this app on Android Studio while changing the entry point (target) to something other than lib/main.dart. I am using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2

When I look at the Edit Configuration dialog in Android Studio I see a screen that is different from the one posted by most people on the net. Here is what I see.

[image]

Comment: what is your need give me details?

Comment: As mentioned above.  I want to run a Flutter app from Android Studio, not from the command line, and I need to pass a different entry point other than main.dart.

Answer (score 0):

With Flutter and Android Studio, here is how I run run my app using flavors and a specific entry point:

```
flutter run --flavor production -t ./lib/main_production.dart
```

Comment: I am aware of this flutter run command, which I am using in VSCode.  My question was, how do I run the Flutter app from Android Studio and not from the command line, given that I need to pass a different entry point other than main.dart?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps in **Android Studio**

Step 1: select edit configuration in the toolbar
[image]

Step 2: Update the name of the entry point and flavor as per your use cases

[image]

---

Same Configuration you can do in **VS Code** as well

Follow [this](https://medium.com/nonstopio/the-hidden-gems-of-vs-code-settings-json-and-launch-json-explained-9e9e1c6b4b4a) article for configuring launch.json as per the environment

Comment: I have updated the issue above to show the Edit Configuration dialog in Android Studio.  I see a different dialog than the one you posted over here.  I am not sure why.